# Replace callback hell with observable

Tags: javascript, callback, reactive-programming, rxjs

[RxJS github repo](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) explains how to create observable from event or array. I know how to replace the callback hell with async or Promise, but I couldn't find an example on how to create and return observable for my functions doing async tasks.

[For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098066/what-is-callback-hell-and-how-and-why-rx-solves-it),

```
x = getData();
y = getMoreData(x);
z = getMoreData(y);
...

getData(function(x){
    getMoreData(x, function(y){
        getMoreData(y, function(z){ 
            ...
        });
    });
});
```

How do I replace this callback hell with observables? I found we can call observer.next() method in [RxJS github - creating observable](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/creating.md) but couldn't figure out an implementation for this example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34055587/5433027

Comment: @Thomas It will run all functions in parallel. In my case, it's serial, result of first goes as input to next function and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could use the `flatMap` operator instead to chain results. Have a look here : [RxJS Promise Composition (passing data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701304/rxjs-promise-composition-passing-data/34701912#34701912). Basically chaining promises is the same as chaining `flatMap`. That is :

```
pl().then(p2).then(p3).then(console.log);
```

is similar to :

```
 Rx.Observable.just()
         .flatMap(p1)
         .flatMap(p2)
         .flatMap(p3);
```

So the transition from promises to observables is simple. If you have a function which operates with a callback instead of a promise, I can think of two options :

- Try to use `Rx.Observable.fromCallback` or `Rx.Observable.fromNodeCallback`
- Wrap the callback in an observable of your own. Have a look here too : [rx.js how to chain observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35158387/rx-js-how-to-chain-observables/35159322#35159322)

For instance, `function asyncCall (param, cb)` would lead to something like :

```
Rx.Observable.create (function(observer){
  asyncCall(param, function cb(err, data){
    if (err) {observer.onError(err)}
    else {
      observer.onNext(x);
      // The following is supposing your callback is only called once, so there is no more data
      observer.onCompleted();
    }
  }
})
```

Once that's done you can use `flatMap` (or `concatMap` if order of execution matters) as shown before.

Comment: so I've to pass observer in each function and it has to call observer.onNext() when it finishes, isn't it making callback hell more complicated if we just have 2-4 callbacks?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: You are not alone. I understand you @Ankush. And yes, it's "Observable Hell".

Async/Await is the way to go to make stuff understandable for us mere mortals.